# middle align and move images to the left

Tags: alignment

i have matrix in posterbox.
Minimal working coding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,enumitem,setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=1mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]

\posterbox[colframe=red,width=18cm,height=8cm]{column=1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path(0,0,0);
\matrix[ampersand replacement=\&,matrix of nodes,column sep=10pt, row sep=2pt] at (0.1,0.1,0.02,0.02,0.02) {
\includegraphics[width=2.0cm,height=3.0cm,angle=0,valign=l]{example-image-a} \& abc \& 
\hfill  
\includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0,valign=l]{example-image-b}\&  \includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0,valign=l]{example-image-b}\&  \includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0,valign=l]{example-image-b} \\
\includegraphics[width=2.0cm,height=1.5cm,angle=0,valign=l]{example-image-a} \& abc xyz \& \hfill 
\includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0,valign=l]{example-image-b}\&  \includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0,valign=l]{example-image-b}\&  \includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0,valign=l]{example-image-b} \\
\includegraphics[width=2.0cm,height=2.0cm,angle=0,valign=l]{example-image-a} \& abc xyz mlk \& \hfill 
\includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0,valign=l]{example-image-b}\&  \includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0,valign=l]{example-image-b}\&  \includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0,valign=l]{example-image-b} \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

Please see attachment.

Please help:

1/ middle align of image a, 3 images b and text

2/ move 3 images b to the left ( /hfill don't work)

3/ how can increase/decrease distance between 3 images b?

Thanks

image that i need:

[image]

Image from my code:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This addresses your questions on the vertical alignment and column distances.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,enumitem,setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=1mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]

\posterbox[colframe=red,width=18cm,height=8cm]{column=1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[ampersand replacement=\&,matrix of nodes,column sep=10pt, row sep=2pt,
nodes={anchor=center}, %<- center nodes including pictures
column 1/.append style={column sep=3cm},% <- increase specific column separation
column 2/.append style={column sep=4cm},% <- increase specific column separation
] (mat) at (0.1,0.1,0.02,0.02,0.02) {
\includegraphics[width=2.0cm,height=3.0cm,angle=0]{example-image-a} \& abc \& 
\includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0]{example-image-b}\&  \includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0]{example-image-b}\&  \includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0]{example-image-b} \\
\includegraphics[width=2.0cm,height=1.5cm,angle=0]{example-image-a} \& abc xyz \& \hfill 
\includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0]{example-image-b}\&  \includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0]{example-image-b}\&  \includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0]{example-image-b} \\
\includegraphics[width=2.0cm,height=2.0cm,angle=0]{example-image-a} \& abc xyz mlk \& \hfill 
\includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0]{example-image-b}\&  \includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0]{example-image-b}\&  \includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=0.5cm,angle=0]{example-image-b} \\
};
\fill[white] foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{([xshift=1em,yshift=-1em]mat-\X-1.east) rectangle
([xshift=-1em,yshift=1em]mat-\X-2.west)
([xshift=1em,yshift=-1em]mat-\X-2.east) rectangle
([xshift=-0.1em,yshift=1em]mat-\X-3.west)}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me note that I do not know if it is always harmless to put a `tikzpicture` inside a `tcolorbox`. Rather, I suspect that this amounts to nesting `tikzpictures`. It seems to work but it should be noted that it would be straightforward to add the frame and background with Ti*k*Z. Also your figure is a bit too wide.

Comment: How can move 3 images B more to the left? example: space = 0.1 cm to left vertical of table. Thanks

Comment: @latexforti These distances are controlled by the individual column seps. However, I do not quite understand what "to left vertical table" means (and am not really online right now).

Comment: sorry, like right margin = 0.1 cm, distance between (last image B) and vertical line of box = 0.1cm. Thanks

Comment: @latexforti Yes, this is possible, but at this point the whole setup is not really optimal. Apart from the possible issue of nesting `tikzpicture`s the whole setup is not very symmetric. So I think it might make more sense to clarify first what you really want to achieve. Do you really want to have a posterbox, or is it just a means to get the frame and the background? Do you really want a poster of width `width=12cm` but a box inside of width `width=18cm`? It will be much more efficient to clarify these things beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

like this?

[image]

in your case `\hfill` not help to push last three columns to the right. you need to increase width of the second column and if necessary `column sep`. for example with

```
    column 2/.style={nodes={minimum width=5cm},
                     column sep=25mm}]
```

also you can make MWE code a little bit shorter with use `Gin` key for images in matrix. for vertical centering you need to put images baseline to the center (by `valign=center`, as already showed in @marmot answer)}:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,enumitem,setspace}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=1mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]

\posterbox[colframe=red,width=18cm,height=8cm]{column=1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\setkeys{Gin}{height=1cm,width=1cm}
\path(0,0,0);
\matrix[ampersand replacement=\&,
        matrix of nodes,
        column sep=10mm,
        row sep=2pt,
        column 2/.style={nodes={minimum width=4cm},
                         column sep=30mm}]
{
\includegraphics[height=3.0cm,width=2cm,
                 valign=c]{example-image-a} \&
                                       abc  \&
\includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-b} \&
\includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-b} \&
\includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-b} \\
\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2cm,
                 valign=c]{example-image-a} \& 
                                    abc xyz \& 
\includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-b} \&  
\includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-b} \&
\includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-b} \\
\includegraphics[height=2.0cm,width=2cm,
                 valign=c]{example-image-a} \&
                                abc xyz mlk \&
\includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-b} \&
\includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-b} \&
\includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-b} \\

};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This produces a symmetric spacing but in the OP's screenshot it is not symmetric.

Comment: @marmot, you might be right. Now i see, what OPe like to obtain with `\hfill` . Since you already give a hint how to do this, I will probably left answer as it is. It may some ideas from it will be helpful to someone. Meanwhile i will rethinking, if there is short way (without defining new `column sep` for each column)  to increase distance between "b" images (sub question c)., but here is now time to slip/hibernate :-)